# How to pass/return a structure from dbus using C programming?

Tags: c++, linux, gstreamer, dbus

I am building a music player using gstreamer-1.0. I am using sqlite3 to store meta data of the mp3 files. And I would like to use dbus for communication between gstreamer and database. This is basically to isolate the UI and the framework of the music player separately. While doing so I would like to retreive meta data which has been already stored in the database. I am returning it through a structure. Question is, how do I write the xml file for returning a structure through a function. My structure and function are as shown below.`

```
struct string_vars{
  std::string title;
  std::string album;
  std::string artist;
  std::string genre;
  volatile long int real_time;
  volatile long int current_time;
};

struct string_vars Gstreamer_class::req_meta_data(char *song_path
{   
  start_playbin_for_database(song_path);
  return label_data;
}
```

I tried like this:-

```
<method name="req_meta_data">
    <arg type="s" name="song_path" direction="in">      
    <arg type="(issssxx)" name="label_data" direction="out">
</method>
```

I guess its wrong. It threw me an error:-

> Unable to load "value-dbus-music.xml": Can't put  element here
>   make: *** [value-server-stub.h] Error 1

Please help me.

Comment: Need more info. Which dbus libraries are you using? DBUS, as a IPC, let you choose different libraries and languages.

Answer (score 0):

The signature to return **struct string_vars** as out parameter would be as following

```
<method name="req_meta_data">
    <arg type="s" name="song_path" direction="in">      
    <arg type="(ssssxx)" name="label_data" direction="out">
</method>
```

I removed the additional **"i"**.

Now coming to your problem, looks like your build system is configured to autogenerate server side stubs from dbus introspection file named "value-dbus-music.xml". 
Configure build system to look for correct XML file.